# How to deploy spring boot to heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, intellij-idea

I wanted to deploy my application to heroku server and I am facing this problem. Any idea?

```
      [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  13.339 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-09T04:05:01Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project russion_spring_boot: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

```
   <properties>
        <java.version>15.0.1</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: What is the JDK version you are using? Please add the output of `mvn -v`

Comment: Apache Maven 3.8.1  Java version: 15.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Logs depict the error - `invalid target release: 11`. Basically this error means that you have mentioned higher/mismatched version of Java in maven compiler's source and target java version settings in your `pom.xml` compared to the JDK which is being pointed out by `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

To fix this error, just check the Java version in `pom.xml` and `JAVA_HOME`. They should match.

To know more about this issue, check this post - https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-invalid-target-release-17-18-19-or-110

Comment: I think  they match, please take a lookt at my pom.xml file where I wrote  my java version.

Comment: But what is there in `JAVA_HOME`. Can you provide full output of `mvn --version`.

Comment: Yes, sure here it is 
C:\Users\bekja>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 15.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Two changes I would suggest: 1) Change `java.version` to `15` in `pom.xml`. 2) Add `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties in `pom.xml` along with `java.version`. Both will have same value as that of `java.version`.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, here I am getting this problem again 
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compi
ling: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]

Comment: My pom.xml file 
<properties>
  <java.version>15</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

Comment: Oooh men, finally it worked. I don't why but when I change my version 15 to 1.8  I suddenly managed to deploy my app to the  server. But,  thank you bro anyway. I wish I vote but I don't have enought reputations.

Comment: How were you compiling the code? This worked in `1.8`, which shows your maven might be pointing to JDK `1.8` and not `15`.

Comment: How do I know if my maven is pointing to JDK 1.8  or not ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand . What do you mean?

Comment: I mean how are you building the war or jar? What command do you use?